# query for checking database is already existing

Tags: php

how can i check if a database is already existing

Comment: We need more information, what do you require it to work on all different database server types, or just one?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(mysql_select_db('db-name'))
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to check the database

```
select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name='databasename'
```